# mysqldump cron not dumping

Tags: cron, crontab, mysqldump

I am attempting to setup a cron to use mysqldump once a day.  There is no output and I cannot see any database usage while watching `top`.  The crontab is:

```
mysqldump [database] -u[user] -p'[password]' > /home/newvtds/backups/db_backup_`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`.sql
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have other crons for the same user that work correctly

Comment: Have you tried running this command from an interactive shell?  Do you get any errors that way?

Comment: it runs correctly without error when I run it manually.  the crontab times are `31 10 * * *` (I edit the minutes column to test the normal crontab running it [I'm EST])

Comment: Try: sudo grep cron /var/log/syslog to make sure that it is being run.

Comment: I don't have that log file on this system, I'm on CentOS 5

Comment: I don't run CentOS but try checking for /var/log/messages.

Comment: I have an empty messages file.  It IS there, but empty.

Comment: Is cron running?  ps -elf | grep cron.  Do you have any log files that are non-empty?  My RHEL box has /var/log/cron

Comment: i ran ps and got:  `5 S root     17863     1  0  75   0 -   812 stext  Dec10 ?        00:00:03 crond`  most of the log files that have text are full of `^@` but have other text scattered throughout the file

Comment: Any /var/log/cron file?  Can you reboot the server?  Or maybe restart the cron daemon?  sudo /etc/init.d/crond restart

Comment: i restarted the crond service and it started working.  it appears the code was always good, there was just a bug in the crond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the cron daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Comment: it's something so simple... funny how whenever someone asks me for help on their comp, the first thing I have them do i restart, and I forget my own advice... :-)

Comment: Since when crond must be restarted after adding a new cronjob?

Answer (score 3):

In crontab entries, you have to escape the % character. That's your problem:

http://www.ducea.com/2008/11/12/using-the-character-in-crontab-entries/

Answer (score 0):

There are couples of way things may get wrong.

1. You don't need the ' ' for the password.
2. In cron job, always specific the full path for mysqldump. As most of the shell will had PATH setup in the environment variable, cron probably will not make that assumption to avoid execute file hijacking.

And for cron job error, they always get mailed to the user who own it. Check your system mail for more information.

Comment: 1.  I have a special character that starts my mysql password and mysql requests the password be manually entered without the ''  2.  I've changed `mysqldump` to `/usr/bin/mysqldump` but no luck, still didn't run  (3) I have not mail on either the administrator or the user this cron is installed on

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd make sure your `cron` is set up to mail output to you.

I'd add a `MAILTO=youremail@example.com` line to your crontab, and then a test cron to verify output.

something like

```
* * * * * date
```

and make sure you get output.

Also remember that under cron, your `PATH` is very minimal, probably just /usr/bin:/bin.  and no LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Is mysqldump in /bin or /usr/bin?

Comment: to add mail output you just add the mailto example?  ie- `* * * * * date MAILTO=mail@me.com` ? I've changed `mysqldump` to `/usr/bin/mysqldump`

Comment: You can put MAILTO at the start of the file on a line of its own.